# Running ML inference in CPU with real time priority takes longer than default priority

Tags: linux, cpu, priority

I was wondering if setting up realtime priority would help [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp) to run faster, but not only it doesn't run any faster, it runs substantially slower.

I'm running it using `sudo chrt -r 99 ...` from an ssh connection.
This process runs in 4 threads (the CPU has 6 cores).

Why would a process (ML inference) run slower in realtime?

Comment: The threads running in real-time could be starving system threads that are trying to do I/O. It's possible that you have two "free" cores, but every IO may require a chain of threads to do work. If those 4 threads run any threads themselves then those subsequent threads could combine to starve the system of  time. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48519/negatives-of-running-processes-with-real-time-priority